# What is the proper way to store tires to prevent cracking?

Tags: tire, storage

I have several extra tires, two on a spare wheelset, and others in a bundle.  I am not riding as much as I was a year ago, so I will not be wearing out tires as fast as I was.

What is the best way and conditions to store these tires so that the rubber doesn't just crack and split when I put them on wheels and pump them up?

Note: I don't know if it makes a difference, but I live at about 5000' of elevation in a very dry climate; forced air heating is used in my apartment about 6 months a year.

**More info as an example**: I had tires mounted on wheels, deflated, hanging from ceiling hooks.  I don't know how long it was that I hadn't used them but it was probably 12+ months.  When I inflated them a week ago to the recommended pressure the sidewalls showed cracking parallel to the rim on the whole, or nearly the whole circumference of the tire.

Comment: 5000' is 1500m.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A lot of this is guesswork on my part.

**Entire bike:** I would deflate the tires, keep them on rims if possible, and hang the bike up. Putting weight on the tires when they're deflated is probably bad for the tires -- and for the rims.

**Rims with tires**: I would follow [zigdon's answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/what-is-the-proper-way-to-store-tires-to-prevent-cracking/1750#1750) and hang up the rims and deflated tires.

**Bare tires without rims:** I'd store the tires on their sides, not stacked too high. Perhaps putting them in something like a pizza box, or between pieces of cardboard, would help avoid the tires crushing each other.

**In general:** I would also flex the tires every so often, to stop them from getting brittle. Also, ozone is [bad for tires](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tires.html), so I'd not store them near anything that generates ozone (furnaces or electric motors), and I'd store the tires away from extreme heat or cold.

Comment: I think storage in the basement near the furnace may have been my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could always unfurl them, and hang them all off a hook.  That way the weight is all on the hardened parts that connect to the rim, and not on the softer, road-facing, portions.